# Storing a multidimensional array (spreadsheet) in Redis

Tags: python, redis

I am considering using redis to store data of the following nature:

```
data =[
    ['first_name', 'last_name', '', 'x', '', '', 'e'], 
    ['x', '', '', 'x', '', '', 'x'], 
    ['', '', '', 'x']
]
```

This would correspond to a grid that looks similar to:

```
first_name    last_name           x                 e
x                                 x                 x
                                  x
```

As shown from above, the grid can have arbitrary dimensions, and there are no type restrictions.

Here are the four operations I'd need to support, giving a python equivalent as an example:

```
# insert data at a specific cell, A2
data[0][2] = "new value"

# insert a new blank row, at 2
data.insert(1,[])

# insert a new blank column at B
for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i].insert(1,'')

# retrieve all data
print(data)
```

Would redis be a good option to store the above kind of data? If so, how could it be saved to do the above operations? As another option, my thinking was just to store it as a json structure with all the data there and just retrieve the data on-demand every time I need to make an operation (though the data could be up to 50MB and loading that amount of data takes about 2s locally). Still another option would be to store it in something like a DB as `(row,col,value)`.

Answer (score 1):

The question rather to use Redis or any other DB depends on so many system requirements. 
for instance:

1. What is the usage of the db.
2. How fast should you retrieve the data.
3. what is the throughput, I/O.
4. Is that db should be clustered/sharded?

In order to answer your question, if you need to go with redis, for what you described I would go with:

1. structure the data as json/csv.
2. Using redis lists to push additional object to the key, you can read [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/redis/redis_lists.htm)
3. every time you need to read the data stored in the redis you can iterate it with batches (you need to understand what is the best batch for your usage/infra).

Other alternative is using Mongodb. I will elaborate if this option is on the table

Comment: sure, I'm open to anything here. Currently, we're using a relational database to store the data in the format of: `sheet_id,row_num,col_num,val` with the row_num and col_num indexed. The only reason I'm thinking the DB may not be ideal is the network transfer of the data (a common operation is "view all data for sheet").

Comment: `How fast should you retrieve the data.` <-- this is the #1 concern; #2 would be speed to insert/modify the data. Usage of the DB is to display spreadsheet-like data to an end-user. The spreadsheets themselves will be small-ish (under 100MB), so I'm not too concerned with clustering/sharding/etc. for now.

Comment: The network bottleneck will be in any db usage. In addition in case of changing the data stored in redis it will might be not an ideal operation. how often this operation is made... ? In case of view all, the redis query would probably will provide you the fastest results. 
If I was you I would stick to the solution I have today and would have adding a redis as a cache db ( this is it's main purpose), every time you want to query it will first query the redis, in case of changing the data in the db there should be additional operation which should update the redis as well.

Comment: Basically this mean that your queries would always be from redis, which will provide you the fastest result , and the persistency would be with your current implementation with your db, or any other document db which also might be considered, and also can be indexed on some keys

Comment: @Mikey -- thanks for this clarification I think that's a good idea to have it in front of the db for caching. Would you please be able to provide an example of how you store a multidimensional array in redis and then how you would perform one operation (such as insert new row)? I just want to make sure I'm clear on how to store things in redis, as I've never stored anything beyond a basic k/v store.

Comment: Additionally, how would you go about storing multiple types in mysql for the above case? Would you store everything as a string, and perhaps have another id field that gives the type. The schema would then be: `sheet_id,row_num,col_num,val,type_id`?

Comment: As per mysql you can consider using blobs, when it comes to store object in the db. perhaps you can find some examples and knowledge from here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-jdbc-blob

Comment: As per an example to store values in redis, before going to the solution I would like to get a better understanding on what are the values you find important to store in the db, since it may effect the type in redis db.